# VPS IP Grabbing Abuse: VPS using another IP from network by itself

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, ip, vps

I bought a Windows Server 2012 VPS subscription two months back, and deployed a website on it. Everything went fine for the next month and suddenly i receive an email from providers telling me that My VPS is causing serious network disruptions by using another IP from the Network. (this IP to be specific is: 193.164.131.216)

I checked the logs and i couldn't find anything (however, i blocked that IP in the firewall, and told them it was not me.). they emailed me again and said everything is fine now, but they will suspend my server if I did it again (But I didn't do anything!).

Another month passed, and 10 hours ago they suspended my server telling me it was trying to use the same IP again causing serious network disruptions, they are asking me to fix it (remove the IP from server) immediately using VNC connection.

But I have no idea what is going on. Providers charge money for an hour support which i cannot pay at the moment.

What I did on the server:

1: Deployed a ASP.NET MVC website which is a simple photo sharing social network (I have double checked all the code, there is nothing that could cause my VPS to use another IP)

2: For version control I had installed TFS 2012 Express on the server (currently used by me as user only)

3: I installed Sql server 2012 Management studio on it for database Handling

Although I am clueless about the problem but still I have checked the following areas on server

1: Went to Server Manager -> DNS -> Server Properties-> Root Hints. there are alternate IPs here but none of them match the IP (193.164.131.216). Another tab shows a checkbox to handle dns queries on "all IPs" (should i check it to use preferred IP only?)

2: Blocked this IP on the Firewall.

3: Checked the Event logs but i couldn't trace this IP.

4: traced the ip on ip lookup and it s from their own network.

5: checked ipconfig/all but couldn't find this IP again.

It has been 10 hours my server is down. Please if anyone could help me identify the issue and tell me how to fix it, I would really really be thankful.

Comment: I don't see how the server or the applications could "use" an ip address that isn't assigned or bound to the server. Does the server have a static ip address? If so, did you make note of it to see if it's the ip address in question? If the server is dynamically assigned an ip address (via DHCP) then have you made note of it to see if it's the ip address in question? If the ip address in question isn't assigned to the server (either static or dynamic) then the provider is barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: my VPS has a Static / Dedicated IP. I have verified it in the network connection settings and Plesk Control Panel as well. Yes thats what I have been telling them I did not do it. While my server was suspended. I connected to it via VNC credentials checked the IP assigned to my server. and that was the same as before (didn't change). Plesk control panel was disabled at that time so i couldn't check it there. After two they activated my server and said they have removed the IP (193.164.131.216) via Plesk. how is it event possible. I don't have a clue. The provider in question is Contabo.